# <?php ?> syntax error

Tags: php, html

I hope you are doing great
I have been faced with a strange syntax error. when I write the syntax 
it says: unexpected end of file or reached end while parsing. If you know for this error. that's a general question. not for the project

code smaple:

```
<?php
include 'Footer.php';
?>
```

I wonder if you could help me with that.
thanks in advance. cheers,

Comment: Post your footer.php code

Comment: The issue is likely in footer.php

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with `Footer.php`. Probably a missing curly brace. You need to learn how to debug code.

Answer (score -3):

You're most likey missing a closing curly brace in Footer.php.

Check that each opening curly brace has a closing twin, such as:

```
if( $something )
{
    // do something
} // <- check you have these braces equal to opening ones
```